# Failed text validation

Tags: java, loops

I have a snippet of code that consistently gives me an error:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Choose Role: (Manager, Developer, QA) ");
    role = scan.nextLine();
    // For testing:         ///////////////////////
    System.out.println("role is: " + role);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (is_numeric(role)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
        continue;
    } else if (!role.equalsIgnoreCase("MANAGER") || !role.equalsIgnoreCase("DEVELOPER") || !role.equalsIgnoreCase("QA")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Role");
        continue;
    } else {
        break;
    }
} while (true);
```

I added the "For testing" block just to see, if for some reason there is something happening to the variable role, but its not. No matter how I write manager/developer/qa (whether in caps, small letters, etc) the "Invalid Role" is triggered and the loop goes over again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show me some value `a` that will fail test `(a != 1 OR a != 2)`?

Comment: Unrelated, but I would move this out into a separate method, making the mainline code easier to think about. Also, using strings for roles is just painful--consider using an enum, or possibly a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, this test is wrong

```
(!role.equalsIgnoreCase("MANAGER") || 
 !role.equalsIgnoreCase("DEVELOPER") || 
 !role.equalsIgnoreCase("QA"))
```

Why? Because if the role = "MANAGER", it does not equal "DEVELOPER" (or "QA") and vice-versa. I think you wanted

```
(!role.equalsIgnoreCase("MANAGER") && 
 !role.equalsIgnoreCase("DEVELOPER") && 
 !role.equalsIgnoreCase("QA"))
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! I guess in my head it sounded right to say if role doesn't equal manager OR Developer OR qa, then throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
!role.equalsIgnoreCase("MANAGER") || !role.equalsIgnoreCase("DEVELOPER") ||   
              !role.equalsIgnoreCase("QA")
```

Is not what you want, replace `||` with `&&`.

In your code you're saying: If `role` is not "MANAGER" OR if `role` is not "DEVELOPER" OR if `role` is not "QA".

Due to [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), if the first condition is `true`, the others won't be evaluated because `true || anything` is always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Java if test short circuit for boolean expressions.

Change `||` to `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what everyone else is saying, if what you're trying to model is "not valid", then don't distribute the negative over each condition and use `&&`.  It's not modelling the right thing.  Model "valid", put parentheses around it and negate the whole thing:

```
if (!(role.equalsIgnoreCase("MANAGER") || role.equalsIgnoreCase("DEVELOPER") || 
           role.equalsIgnoreCase("QA"))) {
   //...
}
```

But this is a case where a helper method will improve code clarity greatly.  First model what you want to model, not the inverse:

```
public boolean validRole(String role) {
    return role.equalsIgnoreCase("MANAGER") || 
           role.equalsIgnoreCase("DEVELOPER") || 
           role.equalsIgnoreCase("QA");
}
```

Then your if statement is hard to get wrong and documents itself:

```
if (!validRole(role)) {
   //...
}
```